# Unmap error in filetype autocommand

Tags: autocmd, map-operator

I use a plugin for todo.txt file (https://gitlab.com/dbeniamine/todo.txt-vim).

Because I mapped some d[other_letters] in my .vimrc and there's a \d mapped in the plugin, to avoid delays when I type `\d` I want to unmap my mapping only in the *"todo"* files.

The filetype assignement have complex rules, then I don't want to do autocommand on filename or extension, but  I want to trigger it on filetype.
Then I wrote on my .vimrc:

```
augroup enter_todo
    au!
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <leader>db
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <leader>dp
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <leader>dc
    ...
augroup END
```

The problem:
when I open a *"todo"* file everything is fine but if I open another todo file, or even if I open the plugin help (the name match the todo filetype assignement rules, nevertheless it is recognized as help file, I can see that in the status line) an error happens (see the picture below).
[image]

Why?

How could I fix this behaviour?

P.S.:  don't helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping are by default global (valid for all the buffers).
If you `unmap` it you unmap it globally and the next time you try to do so Vim will complains that the mapping is not existing.

I would suggest you to define `\db` and its friend as a `<buffer>` mapping and only define them for non `todo` `filetype`.

```
augroup mymapping
    au!
    autocmd FileType * if &ft!='todo' | map <buffer><leader>db mymappingdb | endif
    autocmd FileType * if &ft!='todo' | map <buffer><leader>dp mymappingdp | endif
    autocmd FileType * if &ft!='todo' | map <buffer><leader>dc mymappingdc | endif
    ...
augroup END
```

If you prefer using `unmap` you could do:

```
augroup mymapping
    au!
    autocmd FileType * map <buffer><leader>db mymappingdb
    autocmd FileType * map <buffer><leader>dp mymappingdp
    autocmd FileType * map <buffer><leader>dc mymappingdc
    " ...
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <buffer><leader>db
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <buffer><leader>dp
    autocmd FileType todo unmap <buffer><leader>dc
augroup END
```

Comment: I don't like this way because if I need to add other filetype or condition I need to mess with the original mapping. No way to unmap "per buffer"? Something like `autocmd FileType todo unmap <buffer><leader>db`? I tried that but it doesn't works.

Comment: I have proposed another version based on `unmap` (and `<buffer>` mapping).

Comment: This seems to be too complicated. Why not make use of proper filetype plugins (and after directory to unmap things not wanted)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, `:unmap` is global so you can't use it to "unmap things not wanted" for a given filetype.

Comment: Of course you can unmap it in a filetype plugin. You just need to remap again when undoing the filetype

Comment: Yes you can unmap in a ftplugin, but "You just need to remap again" is precisely what makes things too complicated. Imagine the hassle of creating some mappings in your vimrc and then unmapping AND remapping them in *n* ftplugins, and doing that gymnastic again for every new mapping. That's silly.

Comment: Vivian, with this solution I got rid of all the errors if I open the faile and then try to reload (`:e`), but the lag after the typing of `\d` is still here. I can't understand why.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the problem without success. The plugin mention `<localleader>` but your question refers to `<leader>` could it be a reason?

Comment: What is the result of the `:verbose nmap \d` command after you have reloaded your todo file?

Comment: GREAT! Thanks to your "kind of magic" I discovered that in the mists of time I mapped another \d (`\data`), and that wasn't unmapped. SOLVED!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad that your problem is now solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

That plugin uses `<LocalLeader>` mappings, not `<Leader>` mappings.

If you don't define the global variables `mapleader` and `maplocalleader`, then `<leader>` and `<localleader>` are *both* assumed to be `\`. That is why the plugin's mapping clash with yours: your `<leader>` and the plugin's `<localleader>` are identical.

Defining `maplocalleader` to something else than what you use for `<leader>` should remove the conflicts you are experiencing:

```
let maplocalleader = " "
```

The above *theoretically* gives you two "leaders": one for your own mappings, the default `\`, and another one for your plugins, `<Space>`, which means no conflict anymore.

This looks good on the surface, but the way `<[local]leader>` is implemented lacks flexibility and has been known for a long time to cause conflicts. For example, plugin A might be a good citizen and use `<localleader>`, but plugin B might use `<leader>`, which would conflict with your own mappings. Or you could have plugin C and plugin D both trying to be good `<localleader>`-mapping citizens but eventually defining the same mappings. Etc. You are also arbitrarily limited to *two* leaders, which is… sad.

I prefer to implement the "leader" mechanism on my own, without any `<leader>` or `<localleader>`. This gives me fewer opportunities for conflicts with plugins AND allows me to use as many "leaders" as I need (currently four).

In a perfect world, all plugins should expose their mappings as `<plug>` mappings anyway, and let their users decide if and what they want to map them to. That plugin does that to a certain extent, but not for every mapping. Too bad.